# How to simplify the formula for the moment of inertia?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

MOI can be defined as a tensor:

$$
\mathbf{I} = \int(rr\mathbf{E} - \mathbf{r}\otimes\mathbf{r})dm
$$

in this formula for angular momentum:

$$
\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{I} \cdot \boldsymbol{\omega}
$$

Now, I want to know why (under what circumstances) and how we can derive the formula:

$$
I = \int r^2_{\perp} dm
$$

I am a little bit confused as we are using the distance from the rotation axis to  $dm$ instead of from the origin.

Comment: Perhaps this might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem

Answer (score 1):

The simpler equation can be arrived at if we find axes that makes the momentum of inertia tensor diagonal.But to do a simple calculation consider the following
$ \textbf{r}= \sum_i r_ie_i $ and so $ \textbf{r}\otimes\textbf{r} $ will have terms that look like $r_1^2e_1 \otimes e_1, r_1 r_2 e_1 \otimes e_2... $. The first term in your expression more explicitly is $ \textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{r}(e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2 + e_3 \otimes e_3 ) $. If compute the $I_{xx}$ or equivanlently $I_{11}$ I will have $\textbf{I}_{11}= r_2^2 e_2 \otimes e_2+r_3^2 e_3 \otimes e_3 $ which is the more familiar $y^2 +z^2$. In other words the simpler equation consists of the terms that are on the diagonal of the first equation. See if you can calculate the $\textbf{I}_{32}$ element just to pick a random element.